# CQWP cannot find Body field in the Announcement content type

Tags: content-type, content-query-web-part

I can create a CQWP for the Announcement content type, but when I export the .webpart and add

```
<property name="CommonViewFields" type="string">Expires,Date;Body,text</property>
```

In my ItemStyles.xsl I have added this to show all the returned fields

```
<xsl:template name="ShowXML" match="Row[@Style='ShowXML']" mode="itemstyle">
    <xsl:for-each select="@*">
        <br />
        Name: <xsl:value-of select="name()" />
        <br />Value:<xsl:value-of select="."  disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

But **Body** always comes back blank.

I have two site collections; one to test and one for production.  The *Test* collection works and returns the body of the announcement, but the *Production* does not.

What should I be looking for?  What could I have customized?

Our admin does not yet have the latest service pack installed, nor do I get much of anything out of them support wise.

Comment: I am seriously questioning the health of our farm.  The support is so poor, I am becoming afraid of data loss.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up using the [Stramit Caml Viewer](http://spcamlviewer.codeplex.com/).  What I learned was that at some point the "Body" field I was looking for had been renamed, and the viewer showed me the correct field to be asking for.

Answer (score 1):

instead of

Expires,Date;Body,text

try

Expires,Date;Body,Note

Comment: I have read that too, but it didn't work.  Neither did RichHTML nor HTML